# How much space is needed for a local variable declared as static?

Tags: c

Specifically, if the function is called n times, will there be n copies of the variable in the data segment?  Or will there be a single slot for that variable that is recycled each time the function is called?

Comment: There is only one. And *"recycled"* isn't the term I would use. Since there's only one variable, any changes made to that variable carry over to the next call of the function.

Comment: A static local exists *once*.  The *same* storage is used for *every* invocation of that function.  It is never "recycled".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Or will there be a single slot for that variable that is recycled each time the function is called?

There is a single "slot" in the program's memory space for the variable. It's used every time the function is executed, even if the function calls back itself recursively or if two threads execute the function at the same time.

This is why you should be careful with static locals because they tend to make functions non-thread-safe. As an alternative you could use thread-local storage but that isn't part of Portable C or use a context object passed as a function parameter.

So this:

```
int foo( int x ) {
    static int y = 5;
    return y += x;
}
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
int y = 5; // if you add the `static` modifier then that restricts the scope of `y` to just this file, it does not affect its lifetime or storage semantics.

int foo( int x ) {
    return y += x;
}
```

Comment: Q: Will it sink, or will it swim?  A: "This is indeed what happens..." ;)

Comment: Yes, that's what I figured.  Just wanted to make sure.  Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: @FoggyDay I clarified my answer.

Comment: Define "portable C", please. Thread local storage is standard C11.